# How do I interpolate a vertical surface in ArcScene 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I have electrical resistivity data with X, Y, and Z values.  I have imported these data into ArcScene and they display as points in the subsurface in a vertical plane, each with its own resistivity value.

Is there any way that I can create a surface of resistivity values that is vertical?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create vertical plane and surfaces in ArcGIS, only 2.5D. You can however create them in an external 3-rd party application, export as 3D DXF and import and view in ArcScene.